# Generating and Verifying password hashes in Node.js same as Python's werkzeug

Tags: node.js, hash, cryptography, passwords, pbkdf2

Im moving an app from Python Flask to ExpressJS.
I need some help with password hashing and veryfying.
In Flask, you can do this:

```py
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
pass = 'abcd'
pass_hash = generate_password_hash(pass)
check_password_hash(pass_hash, pass)
```

And in 4 lines you have a boolean response checking if the password corresponds to the hash.

Now to NodeJS: I know how to create a sha256 hash, a HMAC hash or a cypher, but how would i check the password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is also easy to acheve it in node. Use https://github.com/ncb000gt/node.bcrypt.js/
Here is example for koa.

```
let bcrypt = require('co-bcrypt');

let storedHash = yield bcrypt.hash("user_password", 10, null);   // to get hash

let isValid = yield bcrypt.compare("user_password", storedHash);  // to compare
```

In case you would like to use pbkdf2, here is another example.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
crypto.pbkdf2('secret', 'salt', 100000, 512, 'sha512', (err, key) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(key.toString('hex'));  // 'c5e478d...1469e50'
});
```

Documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_pbkdf2_password_salt_iterations_keylen_digest_callback

Comment: co-bcrypt implements bcrypt, but the wekzeug functions from the question use PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA1. These two methods are completely different (but have the same purpose).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I verify the bcrypt passwords in NodeJS that were created in Python Flask with bcrypt. Hope that helps.

```
const { pbkdf2Sync } = require('node:crypto');

function validatePassword(password, passwordHash) {
  // example: pbkdf2:sha256:150000$weUYb4Vf$cf99f5c4b956b9af7fae3a2ff8d8ba921fd7967a1e001f2af2fdc39754f8fecd

  const code2 = passwordHash.split('$');
  // [0]pbkdf2:sha256:150000,
  // [1]weUYb4Vf
  // [2]cf99f5c4b956b9af7fae3a2ff8d8ba921fd7967a1e001f2af2fdc39754f8fecd
  const code1 = code2[0].split(':');
  // [0]pbkdf2
  // [1]sha256
  // [2]150000
  const salt = code2[1];
  const iterations = parseInt(code1[2], 10);
  const keyLen = 32;
  const digest = code1[1];
  const value = code2[2];

  const derivedKey = pbkdf2Sync(
    password,
    salt,
    iterations,
    keyLen,
    digest
  ).toString('hex');

  return value === derivedKey;
}
```

This is how I generate the Flask Login bcrypt hashes.

```
const { pbkdf2Sync } = require('node:crypto');
const randonstring = require('randomstring');

const password = <TYPE_YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE>;

const headerKey = 'pbkdf2:sha256:150000$';
const salt = randonstring.generate(8);
const iterations = parseInt(150000, 10);
const keyLen = 32;
const digest = 'sha256';

const derivedKey = pbkdf2Sync(
    password,
    salt,
    iterations,
    keyLen,
    digest
  ).toString('hex');

const fullKey = headerKey + derivedKey;
```